# Which format of docstring is the standard?

Tags: python, docstring

I have to document my project with `docstring`, but I found some formats of `docstring`, At least I found [NumPy/SciPy docstrings](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html) , [Pydoc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pydoc.html) , [Epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/) and [Google Docstrings](https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html).

I am confused. Which of the above formats is standard? What format is recommended by python community?

Comment: Basic docstring format is described in PEP8. Numpy has specific extensions that work with sphinx and other doc generators.

Comment: "The good thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from."

Comment: It's only a matter of taste, google's docstring has the advantage of being more concise than numpy's (so they tend to be easier to read as text-docstrings). Both look great with sphinx.